# How to change python decorator value dynamically inside a class

Tags: class, python-decorators, langchain

I want to know how can i replace decorator parameter dynamically.
Here is the code

```
import openai
from langsmith.run_helpers import traceable
class LangSmithClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name  # Fixed the assignment of 'name'

    @traceable(run_type="llm", name="openai.ChatCompletion.create")
    def my_llm(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> dict:
        return openai.ChatCompletion.create(*args, **kwargs)

    @traceable(run_type="chain")
    def my_chain(self, prompt: str) -> str:
        messages = [
            {
                "role": "system",
                "content": "You are an AI Assistant. ",
            },
            {"role": "user", "content": prompt},
        ]
        return self.my_llm(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", messages=messages)

    @traceable(run_type="chain", name='mybot')
    def my_chat_bot(self, text: str) -> str:
        generated = self.my_chain(text)
        return generated

LangSmithClass("ABC").my_chat_bot("how are you")
```

What i want is to replace `name='mybot'` `mybot` with `ABC`. Let say if change i change LangSmithClass("ABC") to LangSmithClass("XYZ"), then i want to change decorator name parameter value to `XYZ` instead of `mybot`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it,

```
    import openai
    from langsmith.run_helpers import traceable
    from typing import Any

    class LangSmithClass:
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name  

        def my_llm(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> dict:
            return openai.ChatCompletion.create(*args, **kwargs)

        def my_chain(self, prompt: str) -> str:
            messages = [
                {
                    "role": "system",
                    "content": "You are an AI Assistant. ",
                },
                {"role": "user", "content": prompt},
            ]
            return self.my_llm(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", messages=messages)

        def my_chat_bot(self, text: str) -> str:
            generated = self.my_chain(text)
            return generated

        def dynamic_trace(self, run_type=None, name=None):
            def outer_wrapper(func):
                @traceable(run_type=run_type, name=name)
                def inner_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                return inner_wrapper
            return outer_wrapper

        def call_my_chat_bot(self, text: str, run_type=None, name=None):
            decorated_func = self.dynamic_trace(run_type=run_type, name=name)(self.my_chat_bot)
            return decorated_func(text)

    # Example:
    obj = LangSmithClass("ABC")
    print(obj.call_my_chat_bot("how are you", run_type="chain", name="custom_bot"))
```

[image]